# Microsoft Teams Ubuntu/Debian package secretly adds APT source and APT key

Tags: apt, dpkg, security

After installing Microsoft Teams, I noticed that the following files were created on my system:

```
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
    /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
```

There was no request / opportunity to choose or decline this, the package installation went without any user interaction, and I noticed these additions entirely by chance.

This is a serious invasion and security breach. Are there any settings in the APT / dpkg system to prevent such breaches?

This also feels to me like it is / should be a policy violation by Microsoft. Does anyone have an idea where to report this to?

Comment: Describe the method you used to install MS Teams

Comment: Easiest is to file a bug against the package.

Comment: @user535733 the installation was a standard one-liner of `dpkg -i teams_1.3.00.5153_amd64.deb`, after downloading that file. I didn't anything like --assume-yes or similar.

Comment: Installing Google Chrome does something similar -- the package includes an apt source for it's own updates. It's not nefarious. There are other examples. Classic Open Source aphorism: If you don't trust the author, then don't install the software in the first place.

Comment: I found that MS does fully document these actions at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/get-clients, at least as of 2020/04/23 anyway.

Comment: Oh, and I just had to join a Teams meeting at work, and the browser-based client works great too (at least in Chrome); zero SW to install!

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty typical; not really anything to be afraid of. For example, Google Chrome does essentially the same thing and more IIRC. Those files were installed so that future updates to the software are easily available for installation. For example, security/bug fixes. Admittedly this does mean that MS could in theory ship anything they wanted in their updates, but since that would damage their reputation, it is unlikely that will happen in practice. Note that as the user of the system, you will still have to install any available updates yourself, so you still have the option of rejecting those updates. Unless of course, you've told your system to automatically install all updates without confirmation, but I suspect you haven't done this given your concern about security.

The only alternatives that Microsoft has in this case are:

1. Don't provide any mechanism for automatic updates. This would be bad for security, since they would have to rely on end users manually downloading and installing every bug-/security-fix for the software. Users are unlikely to do this.
2. Implement some update mechanism outside of your Linux distro's standard package management system. This would be problematic since it would be a duplication of effort, and force users to learn a different update system. Integrating with the standard package management system provides a much more friendly experience.

If you really don't want to receive updates for this application, you can always delete those two files. However, if you want to do this, I'd recommend you first uninstall the software itself, so that you aren't running a never-updated version of it.

Some things Microsoft could improve about the package though:

1. Those files aren't part of the package, so they must be created by
   some form of postinstall script. It'd be nice if the files were
   directly included in the package so that a simple "dpkg -x file.deb"
   would make it obvious they were going to be installed as part of the
   package.
2. Running "apt purge teams" didn't remove the files. It'd be much better if a pre/postuninstall script in the package did this.

Microsoft's forums for user feedback on Teams appears to be:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/

Comment: " Admittedly this does mean that MS could in theory ship anything they wanted in their updates, **but since that would damage their reputation**"  That is not a valid reason.  I agree with TS.

Comment: I'm not afraid that Microsoft will send me a "security update" from Linux to Windows tomorrow, but not convinced that they'd never do such a thing either, and definitely not convinced that damaging their reputation would stop them. My solution for now is to manually remove / quarantine those files. For me, this was the first time any files came into /etc/apt by anything other than me putting them there (except those generated during Ubuntu installation). I hope this doesn't become normal, as that would mean I'd have to check /etc/apt for unwanted addition each time I install a new package.

Comment: Do note that simply by running this SW, you're allowing MS to do almost anything to your computer anyway, irrespective of whether you allow updates. The only potential difference is that an update can do things as root during pre/post-install scripts or installing cron jobs or setuid executables, whereas anything they do while you're simply running their SW can only run as your own user ID, unless you've got sudo enabled.

Comment: Oh, and I'd *strongly* recommend that you re-enabled those update files, if not permanently, then at least every time you install updates. Otherwise, you'll never get security fixes for the teams app, which is a very bad state to be in. If you feel that badly about it, then I suggest simply uninstalling teams

Comment: My plan is to check for updates to Teams at times by (1) doing a routine update from the normal sources, (2) scrutinising any updates from the Microsoft repo, (3) installing them if I think they're ok and (4) deleting the files.

I agree there are more ways to stealthily download and install software, but that's not making adding to /etc/apt acceptable. In the longer term I'd very much like a hardened version / option for the apt tools that check whether packages put files in sensitive places.

Answer (score 1):

A solution given by: Kai Kasurinen (kai-kasurinen)
To remove the files of MA TEAMS which been created after installing Microsoft Teams.
The following files were created on my system:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
```

SOLUTION (by Kai Kasurinen (kai-kasurinen) )

--

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg

--

To remove the files installed on package post-install configure and not removed.

Comment: yes, removing the offending files (or "quarantining" them by moving them to somewhere apt won't find them) is a solution. I'd prefer something more sustainably, though -- e.g. ways to alert me to the creation of these files upon installing (updates of) Teams, or to automatically catch and remove / quarantine them.