# Rotating GPG keys used by Debian repository with minimal friction

Tags: apt, repository

I maintain a semi-public server with Debian packages. In a not so distant future, the GPG keys used to sign the packages indexes are going to expire. Therefore, I'm looking for best practices to rotate the keys with minimal friction for the users.

So far, all users have configured the repository in a way similar to [the instructions in the Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository) by explicitly downloading the GPG key and loading it into apt:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.example.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

This works great for the initial configuration, but it is a pain if the keys need to be rotated: As soon as I swap the key on the repository, all users get errors because the package indexes are suddenly signed with a different key.

Some proprietary applications automatically install (and potentially replace) their GPG keys during installation and update (see [Microsoft Teams Ubuntu/Debian package secretly adds APT source and APT key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225671/microsoft-teams-ubuntu-debian-package-secretly-adds-apt-source-and-apt-key)). This comes off creepy. Another option could be to add a package that only contains the GPG keys and instruct the users to install that.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Various, Bionic and newer.

Comment: Specifically the "the Server with Debian packages", is it running Ubuntu or Debian, and which version? Unless this server is running Ubuntu, Debian by itself is off-topic.

Comment: Ubuntu Bionic. Clients are everything (all maintained versions of Ubuntu, Debian, Mint).